# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MembershipTypesId'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

View class

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MembershipTypesId, "MembershipTypesId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("MembershipTypesId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MembershipTypesId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

UsersController

```
        public ActionResult Register(Customers customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (CDBContext dc = new CDBContext())
                {
                    dc.Customers.Add(customer);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    customer = null;
                    ViewBag.MembershipTypesId = new SelectList(dc.MembershipTypes, "MembershipTypesId", "Name");
                    ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";
                }
            }
            return View(customer);
        }
```

I used the same code for the others view and controller but somehow only this got the error. I tried to remove the **null** but it still the same.

Comment: Why not pass list directly with the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your error message suggest is that you are don't have `ViewData` that you should pass on this `DropDownList`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MembershipTypesId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It is looking for ViewData with name `MembershipTypesId`

Your code on controller is correct **IF** you don't have problem on `ModelState`, but what if you have an error in your `ModelState`? Where is your `ViewData` that you need to pass back on your View?

This should be populated before you return to your View from your Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Register(Customers customer)
  {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         //Business Logic
     }
     ViewBag.MembershipTypesId = new SelectList(dc.MembershipTypes, "MembershipTypesId", "Name");
     return View();
  }
```